# regex - append file contents after first match

Tags: linux, awk, sed, text-processing

Say I have the following kinds of files:

`file1.txt`:

```
a a c
b b c
c c c
d d c
e e c
a a c
b b c
c c c
d d c
e e c
```

`file2.txt`:

```
—————
—————
—————
```

How do I get the contents from `file2.txt` so that I end up with `file1.txt` that says:

```
a a c
b b c
c c c
—————
—————
—————
d d c
e e c
a a c
b b c
c c c
d d c
e e c
```

...without just adding the contents after the 3rd line (first line with `c c c`).

Comment: I gave -1 since I did not see any attempt  to solve it.

Comment: @Jotne okay, but there are 2 beautiful answers.

Comment: That is not the point.  With reputation on more than 700 you should now that we are here to help you with codes, not provide complete solution for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `GNU sed` (The command needs to be spread across multiple lines):

```
sed '0,/c c c/ {
    /c c c/r file2.txt
}' file1.txt
a a c
b b c
c c c
—————
—————
—————
d d c
e e c
a a c
b b c
c c c
d d c
e e c
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{buf = buf $0 RS;next} {print} /c c c/ && !done{ printf "%s", buf; done=1  }' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: Any reason you used print inside a block instead of 1 ?

Comment: Just for clarity, I'm a fan of using `1` at the end of a script for brevity and where it's easy to see, but I feel it's easy for anyone reading it to miss a `1;` in the middle of a script so in the middle of a script I tend to use the explicit `{print}`.

Comment: Fair enough, nice answer :)